# Getting Yaml string without class tags

Tags: java, serialization, tags, yaml, yamlbeans

Is there a method to hide all tags from the output of the YamlWriter using the yamlbeans lib?

```
public <T> String toYaml(T object) {
    try (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
        YamlWriter writer = new YamlWriter(stringWriter);
        writer.write(object);
        writer.getConfig().writeConfig.setWriteRootTags(false);//replaces only root tag
        writer.close(); //don't add this to finally, because it the text will not be flushed
        return removeTags(stringWriter.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private String removeTags(String string) {
    //a tag is a sequence of characters starting with ! and ending with whitespace
    return removePattern(string, " ![^\\s]*");
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the writers config to never write class names and you're good to go:

```
writer.getConfig().writeConfig.setWriteClassname(YamlConfig.WriteClassName.NEVER);
```